# Keep the last registered state of a Spinner Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, spinner

I am developing an application which has some switch buttons, which have `SharedPreferences` so that when the application is closed and reopened, the previously activated buttons remain so.

SharedPreferences in the MainActivity class:

```
private Spinner spipol;
    private Switch quim, fil, fis, tri, esp, engl, inf, eti, reli, est, pol, dib, edf, mate;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, sharfil, sharquim, shardfis, shartrig, sharesp, sharemater, sharing, sharinf, shareti, sharrel, sharest, sharpol, sharedf;
    public static final String ex1 = "switch1";
    public static final String ex = "switch";

 dib = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("dib", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        dib.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(ex, false));
        dib.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    editor.putBoolean(ex, true);
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean(ex, false);
                }
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
```

What I need is to know how I can do something similar to what I have with the switch buttons, but with my spinner:

```
spipol = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spipol);
       String [] options = {"", "Short assignment", "Workshop", "Study", "Questions", "Review"};
       ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, options);
       spipol.setAdapter (adapter);
   }
```

I searched the internet for how to do it, but in all the places I saw, they used a save button, what I would like to know is if I can do this without the need to implement this button.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
 spipol.setOnItemSelectedListener (new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener () {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected (AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CaptureSpinner = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition (position);
                index = position;
                System.out.println ("Index:" + index);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView <?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }
public void savePreference (Context context, int index) {
    SharedPreferences sharpref = getPreferences (getApplicationContext (). MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit ();
    editor.putInt ("Data", index);
    System.out.println ("Index:" + index);
    editor.apply ();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change the `savePreference()` to the code below. you don't need to pass a Context or position. you can get the item selected directly from your Spinner to be able to call this method on `onStop()`

```
 public void savePreference() {
        SharedPreferences sharpref = getSharedPreferences("Spinner", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();
        editor.putInt("Data", spipol.getSelectedItemPosition());
        System.out.println("Index:" + spipol.getSelectedItemPosition());
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Call the mothod above in the `onStope()` method :

```
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        savePreference();
    }
```

And on your `onCreate()` you just need to call this :

```
 spipol = findViewById(R.id.spipol);
        String[] options = {"", "Short assignment", "Workshop", "Study", "Questions", "Review"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, options);
        spipol.setAdapter(adapter);

        // here to restore the last selected item 
        SharedPreferences sharpref = getSharedPreferences("Spinner", MODE_PRIVATE);
        spipol.setSelection(sharpref.getInt("Data", 0));
```